# React bootstrap carousel onSelect event

Tags: javascript, react-bootstrap

In jquery with the use of event.currentTarget to get the elements of the next slide to see if exists a attribute and replace with another and at the end remove the event listener when all the attributes (data-background) of the slider have been replaced.

```
$(this).on('slide.bs.carousel', function (event) {
    var nextSlider = event.relatedTarget;
    if(typeof $(nextSlider).attr('data-background') != 'undefined'){
        $(nextSlider).attr("style",'cursor:pointer; '+'background:'+$(nextSlider).attr('data-background')+" no-repeat center center");
        $(nextSlider).removeAttr('data-background');
    }
    if($(this).find('.item[data-background]').length==0){
        $(this).off('slide.bs.carousel');
    }
});
```

Now using the react bootstrap carousel and want to get the next elements of the carousel when it slides (as in example above) where the name for the event that triggers is [onSelect](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/) but don't know what is the name of method for event equivalent of the event.currentTarget??

```
  handleSelect(selectedIndex, event) {
    console.log('carousel new slide....');

    var nextSlider = event.currentTarget;
    if(typeof nextSlider.attributes.getNamedItem('data-src') != 'undefined'){
      console.log('haves data-src');
    }else{
      console.log('doesn\'t haves data-src');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed to use in `handleSelect(selectedIndex, event)` the selectedIndex to update the Component state and re-render with the Items of the next slide of carousel with the attribute src.